# Getting incomplete data from mock API in emulator

Tags: android, flutter, rest, jsonplaceholder

I'm making a simple project to learn REST API integration in flutter, the project was almost done and I made the whole thing while running in web and it worked perfectly, but now when I run it in emulator, the data from user API does not show and by using `debugPrint` it shows that the incomplete data is fetched. The program is not showing any error and I do not understand why is it not working with the emulator, I also connected my own smartphone and the same issue is in my phone as well. I also used another Posts mock API and it is working just fine. This is the method I used to fetch data:

```
Future<List<Users>> getUsers() async {
    try{
      var response =await http.get(Uri.parse(baseUrl));
      debugPrint("Get User Response");
      debugPrint(response.body);
      debugPrint(response.statusCode.toString());

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var jsonData = jsonDecode(response.body);
        debugPrint("this is jsonData $jsonData");
        final json_ = jsonData['users'] as List<dynamic>;
        List<Users> users = json_.map((e) => Users.fromMap(e)).toList();
        debugPrint("this is users $users");
        return users;
      }
      else{
        return Future.error("Server Error");
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      return Future.error("Error Fetching Data");
    }
  }
```

this is what the `debugPrint()` is printing

> I/flutter (22977): Get User Response
> I/flutter (22977): {"users":[{"id":1,"firstName":"Terry","lastName":"Medhurst","maidenName":"Smitham","age":50,"gender":"male","email":"atuny0@sohu.com","phone":"+63 791 675 8914","username":"atuny0","password":"9uQFF1Lh","birthDate":"2000-12-25","image":"https://robohash.org/hicveldicta.png","bloodGroup":"A−","height":189,"weight":75.4,"eyeColor":"Green","hair":{"color":"Black","type":"Strands"},"domain":"slashdot.org","ip":"117.29.86.254","address":{"address":"1745 T Street Southeast","city":"Washington","coordinates":{"lat":38.867033,"lng":-76.979235},"postalCode":"20020","state":"DC"},"macAddress":"13:69:BA:56:A3:74","university":"Capitol University","bank":{"cardExpire":"06/22","cardNumber":"50380955204220685","cardType":"maestro","currency":"Peso","iban":"NO17 0695 2754 967"},"company":{"address":{"address":"629 Debbie Drive","city":"Nashville","coordinates":{"lat":36.208114,"lng":-86.58621199999999},"postalCode":"37076","state":"TN"},"department":"Marketing","name":"Blanda-O'Keefe","title":"Help Desk Operator"},"ein":
> I/flutter (22977): 200
> I/flutter (22977): this is jsonData {users: [{id: 1, firstName: Terry, lastName: Medhurst, maidenName: Smitham, age: 50, gender: male, email: atuny0@sohu.com, phone: +63 791 675 8914, username: atuny0, password: 9uQFF1Lh, birthDate: 2000-12-25, image: https://robohash.org/hicveldicta.png, bloodGroup: A−, height: 189, weight: 75.4, eyeColor: Green, hair: {color: Black, type: Strands}, domain: slashdot.org, ip: 117.29.86.254, address: {address: 1745 T Street Southeast, city: Washington, coordinates: {lat: 38.867033, lng: -76.979235}, postalCode: 20020, state: DC}, macAddress: 13:69:BA:56:A3:74, university: Capitol University, bank: {cardExpire: 06/22, cardNumber: 50380955204220685, cardType: maestro, currency: Peso, iban: NO17 0695 2754 967}, company: {address: {address: 629 Debbie Drive, city: Nashville, coordinates: {lat: 36.208114, lng: -86.58621199999999}, postalCode: 37076, state: TN}, department: Marketing, name: Blanda-O'Keefe, title: Help Desk Operator}, ein: 20-9487066, ssn: 661-64-2976, userAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Window

and this is my `fromMap` method

```
factory Users.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Users(
      id: map['id'] as int,
      firstName: map['firstName'] as String,
      lastName: map['lastName'] as String,
      maidenName: map['maidenName'] as String,
      age: map['age'] as int,
      gender: map['gender'] as String,
      email: map['email'] as String,
      phone: map['phone'] as String,
      username: map['username'] as String,
      password: map['password'] as String,
      birthDate: map['birthDate'] as String,
      image: map['image'] as String,
      bloodGroup: map['bloodGroup'] as String,
      height: map['height'] as num,
      weight: map['weight'] as double,
      eyeColor: map['eyeColor'] as String,
      hair: map['hair'] as Map,
      domain: map['domain'] as String,
      ip: map['ip'] as String,
      address: map['address'] as Map,
      macAddress: map['macAddress'] as String,
      university: map['university'] as String,
      bank: map['bank'] as Map,
      company: map['company'] as Map,
      ein: map['ein'] as String,
      ssn: map['ssn'] as String,
      userAgent: map['userAgent'] as String,
    );
  } //
```

But I do know it's not an issue with the `fromMap` method since everything works just fine on web but it has something to do with the incomplete response because since the response is incomplete the `fromMap` method doesn't work it is not being converted to user instance

User API = https://dummyjson.com/users
Posts API = https://dummyjson.com/posts

Comment: can you add the content of your `fromMap` method?

Comment: @diegoveloper I have edited question with addition of the fromMap method

Comment: don't you see this message?  debugPrint("this is users $users");?  inside the catch add a print :   print('error: ${e.toString()}');